# css hover over li, blur all others

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to use css to blur the `ul` elements containing `a`,`d`,`e` when the user moves their mouse over the element containing `c`, without using JavaScript?

Comment: doen't you mean "blur the li elements"? and what does "blur" mean in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4TMS/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 2px;
}

ul:hover li {
    opacity: .5;
}

ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Nice :) You even took the time to make a jsfiddle demo... I guess you had to first figure out if it actually works hehe

Comment: +1 Tested that in chrome, works nicely - I'm guessing that it will need to be extended for *other* browsers

Comment: @amelvin Of course it works in other browsers :) Except older versions of IE that is.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Netscape 4 might struggle too.

Comment: @amelvin Netscape 4? You mean the one from '97?

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this using form inputs, more specifically text boxes? I've been attempting with :focus but so far nothing works that I have tried.

Answer (score 6):

As opposed to using multiple selectors, you can combine them into one using the `:not` selector.

```
ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Which will set `opacity:.5` on all the `li`, exept the one being hovered over.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2JReM/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/tQnzx/), which is not supported in all browsers due to the `text-shadow` attribute:

```
ul:hover li {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
    color: transparent;
}

ul:hover li:hover {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: black;
}
```

**EDIT:** Added a link to a jsfiddle above, since that's apparently the cool thing that gets you votes.  :P

Comment: No, speed gets you votes :) I +1 him because his answer was 20 seconds faster.

Comment: Quality eventually wins, but not always :/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      ul li {
        margin: 2px; /* Adds 2px of margin around each list item */
      }
    
      ul:hover li {
        opacity: .5; /* Reduces the opacity to 0.5 when the list is hovered */
      }

      ul li:hover {
        opacity: 1; /* Restores the opacity to 1 when an individual list item is hovered */
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Start of the unordered list -->
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
      <li>e</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End of the unordered list -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a slight issue* in my CSS implementation. Initially, when I hovered over the `ul` element, but not directly over any `li` element (which might include padding or `grid` type of display with empty areas), all `li` elements were getting blurred. This was not what I wanted. My goal was to blur all other `li` elements only when a `li` element is hovered over, not when hovering over the `ul` element itself.

To fix this, I adjusted my CSS like so:

```css
ul:has(li:hover) li:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Aa</li>
  <li>Bb</li>
  <li>Cc</li>
  <li>Dd</li>
  <li>Ee</li>
</ul>
```